# File download not prompting download in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-core

I have been struggling to get a pdf file to download in my application. I think I have done everything right, the code execution was successful without error but still, there is no prompt for download.

I created a new project to try the same code and it went well with a prompt for download.

After some time I decided to leave that and do other stuff in the app while I come back to it.
I implementing another file download, which is also not working. At this point, I feel something is definitely wrong but I can't figure it out.

The first download method.
Here I am converting HTML string to pdf and download it to the system.
I am using syncfusion,

```
 public IActionResult ExportToPDF(string htmlContent)
        {
            //Initialize HTML to PDF converter 
            HtmlToPdfConverter htmlConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter(HtmlRenderingEngine.WebKit);
            WebKitConverterSettings settings = new WebKitConverterSettings();

            

            //Set WebKit path
            settings.WebKitPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "QtBinariesWindows");
            //Assign WebKit settings to HTML converter
            htmlConverter.ConverterSettings = settings;

            //HTML string and Base URL 
            string htmlText = htmlContent;
            string baseUrl = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "img");
        
            PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert(htmlText, baseUrl);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            document.Save(stream);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "HtmlOutput.pdf");
        }
```

The second one here
In this method, I have a folder in the www folder. its a sample. I want users to download a sample file

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadSampleFile()
        {
            // Since this is just and example, I am using a local file located inside wwwroot
            var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "FC_Customer.xlsx");
            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return File(memory, GetMimeTypes()[ext], Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
```

Comment: Does it work when you are debugging locally?

Comment: The app is still in the localhost, not deployed to production yet. And it runs successfully but no prompt/dialog box for download

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Does the download show up automatically in your downloads without prompt?

Comment: I am using Microsoft edge currently, and the download does not show in my download folder

Comment: Try this and tell me if it works: https://pastebin.com/95AuExZb Fill in your own file on your disk